# how to feed output from the previous time step along with the input to next rnn cell in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

for a given input we have got hidden and output state from an RNN cell. Now I want to combine the output with the next input for the next RNN cell. How can I do it?

I tried to concat input with the output from the previous step and dummy initialise the first output which is to be concatenated with the input at t=0?

Comment: Please share your current implementation, as well as the error message with the attempt you tried yourself. I've implemented something similar myself and it worked, so I want to try and find out what went wrong.